# mysql query between days and calculate days between dates

Tags: mysql, sql

i need to get the id and days count between days.

```
INSERT INTO Events
    (`ID`, `START`, `END`)
VALUES
    (2313, '2019-07-29', '2019-08-10'),
    (41, '2019-06-22', '2019-07-01'),
    (2540, '2019-06-22', '2019-07-02'),
    (2234, '2019-06-28', '2019-07-12'),
    (2634, '2019-06-30', '2019-07-04'),
    (53, '2019-06-30', '2019-07-02'),
    (1869, '2019-06-30', '2019-07-15'),
    (2132, '2019-07-30', '2019-08-10')
;
```

**my query is**

```
SELECT `ID`
  FROM Events 
 WHERE `START` BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31' 
   AND `END` BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31';
```

i need output as

```
2313 - 3
41 - 1
2540 - 2
2234 - 12
.....
```

please help me.

Comment: What is the second part 2313 - 3 (this 3 ??)

Comment: I might be wrong but no row satisfies the condition.

Comment: sorry, i need output as 2313 - 3, 41 - 1, 2540 - 2, 2234 - 12

Comment: @YathavSriTechnology Second time from where comes  2313 - 3 (this 3 ??)

Comment: Second time from where comes 2313 - 3 is days count

Comment: Based on the data and condition, there should be no ouput. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GREATEST returns max value from list, LEAST - min

```
select ID, 
       DATEDIFF(LEAST(`END`,'2019-07-31'), GREATEST(`START`, '2019-07-01')) + 1
from events
```

Comment: Thanks @splash58, i got exact output when i changed the date condition i get in-correct data. query is "select ID, 
       DATEDIFF(LEAST(`END`,'2019-06-30'), GREATEST(`START`, '2019-06-01')) 
from events"

Comment: @YathavSriTechnology consider [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=da35a88600085d0defad9cf4256b52fd)

Comment: Finally i got the result by passing condition. "select ID, 
       DATEDIFF(LEAST(`END`,'2019-08-31'), GREATEST(`START`, '2019-08-01')) + 1 as dDate 
from events
having dDate > 0;"

Comment: @YathavSriTechnology Very well.  I did not think about where condition :(

Answer (score 1):

use DATEDIFF() function.

```
SELECT `id`, DATEDIFF(`start`, `end`) 
FROM `events` 
WHERE 
 `start` BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31' AND
 `end` BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31';
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not provide a solution for OP's question. Here's the [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=d37354aa09e44c9bd83243ca4f6eb9d8)

Comment: when i change the date in query it showing negative value. i need output for between the date criteria not to show all the rows. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=a7aeeea2dd9e97b1f1d4d7e90f50b1df